# MS Access save picture from clipboard as jpg

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm looking for code to save screenshot from clipboard as jpg file directly in MS access or VBA method to convert bmp to jpg. I found workaround but I'm not satisfied with its speed. (I'm using MS Access to open excel file, run code to paste and save picture as jpg, code below).

I found [working code](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/260955-how-do-i-save-bitmap-image-clipboard-bmp-file.html) but it saves picture as *.bmp.

I'm using MS Access 2016

Code in MS Access file:

```
Sub Copy_screenshot_to_file()
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim qSQL As String

Dim xl As Object
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlPath As String
Dim fPath As String
fPath = "\\XXX\"      'New file location
xlPath = "\\XXX...\Export to JPG tool.xlsm"      'excel file location

Dim dwg_nr As String
Dim row_nr As Long
Dim fName As String
Dim lName As String
Dim Date1 As Date

dwg_nr = Screen.ActiveForm![PID_nr].Value
row_nr = Screen.ActiveForm![ID_num].Value

'file name gen
Date1 = Now()
fName = dwg_nr & " " & Format(Date1, "yyyy.dd.mm hh-mm")
lName = fPath & fName & ".jpg"


'generate screenshot
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open (xlPath)
xl.Visible = True '
xl.Run "RunCodeFromAccess", fName, fPath
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing

If Dir(lName) = "" Then
    MsgBox "JPG file not created, please make new screenshot"
    Exit Sub
End If


'add link to DB
qSQL = "UPDATE tblXXX SET Field12 = '" & lName & "' WHERE ID_num = " & row_nr
db.Execute qSQL, dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

Code in excel file:

```
Sub RunCodeFromAccess(Fname As String, fPath As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Paste
'Range("A1").Paste
Dim oDia As Object
Dim oChartArea
Dim sh As Shape
Dim PicName As String

For Each sh In ws.Shapes
PicName = Fname
    sh.CopyPicture
    Set oDia = ws.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, sh.Width, sh.Height)
    Set oChartArea = oDia.Chart
    oDia.Activate
    With oChartArea
        .ChartArea.Select
        .Paste
        .Export (fPath & PicName & ".jpg")
    End With
    oDia.Delete
sh.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: How did the image **get onto** the clipboard in the first place?

Comment: Hold On, what are you ***actually*** trying to do?  Is the goal to save an Excel chart as an image?  It seems like you're trying to find a workaround for a workaround for a workaround.  Your code shows an Excel Chart, yet your Question says Excel, and there's no indication of why it needs to be saved as a JPG as opposed to PNG or BMP.  Please, you need to give more information about what you're ***actually trying to do***.

Comment: I'm trying to update a tool that saves snapshots created with W7 default Snipping Tool. When user have a comment regarding drawing or other document he can simply make a screenshot of problematic area with Snipping Tool, select row in MS Access datasheet form and press "add" button. Current version of script uses external excel file (chart object) to make jpg and add link to specific row in MS Access form.

I found that possible solution may be freeimage.dll. I managed to convert image format but I'm struggling with connection to clipboard...

Comment: So you currently have VBA for Excel that inserts a JPG into an Access table?  It currently works but you're trying to eliminate Excel as a "middle-man", correct?  Please post that code.

Comment: Code added. GoaI is to get rid of "middle-man" (excel) and do whole thing in MS Access. Now I have Access VBA that opens excel file and runs sub stored in excel file. Image in clipboard is pasted to excel worksheet, converted to chart object, saved to specific folder. When done excel file is closed without saving.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but in case if you are still interested in this function. You can have a look at my [VBA Tools Dll](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/blob/master/README.md#save-clipboard-images-to-local-file) Which allows to save clipbord images to a location you provide. There is a sample accdb file with vba wrapper for download in the sample folder.

using vba wapper from the sample file it would be:

```
SaveClipboardToImage()
```

or

```
SaveClipboardToImage(Optional Path As String = "", Optional FileNAme As String = "", Optional FileType As String = "jpeg")
```

which will return the full filepath where your file has been saved as or "" if no Image is found in clipboard.

Please feel free to use online antivirus scanners before using any dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Anything's possible but (for lack of further information) I suspect the suitable answer in this case is **it's not possible**.  At least not with the help of third-party utilities or other programming languages.

To understand why, you need to understand how the clipboard works.  Here's some [.NET documentation about the Clipboard Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx), but she short version is: not everything is stored the same way on a clipboard.

- When the clipboard stores a copied image, it's stored as Bitmap, always.
- When the clipboard stores a file (like a JPG), it's not storing the actual data; it's storing a "pointer" to the file.  If you copy a JPG file to the clipboard, and delete the file, it can't be retrieved from the Clipboard either.

**Based on your code**, I suspect what you're *trying* to do doing is copy a chart from Excel (or something similar) to the clipboard and wanting to save it to a file, as a workaround towards saving the object directly to file.

If you're trying to save an Excel Object like a chart as a JPG File then do it directly:

```
ActiveChart.Export "c:\outputPath\outputFileName.jpg", "JPG"
```

Other graphics filters can also be used, depending on what's installed on your machine.

---

### More information:

- MSDN : [**Chart.Export Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-export-method-excel)
- [How to easily export Excel Charts as Images](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/export-excel-charts-as-images)

---

<sub>(I suspect this is example of a common problem around here: the [**XY Problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378):  Programmer Bob is stuck on problem X, which he doesn't know how to solve.  He comes up with potential solution Y, but doesn't know exactly how to solve that either, so Bob asks for help with problem Y, which almost always results in unnecessary work for everyone involved, when Bob should have just asked about problem X.)</sub>

Comment: In this case... do not ["be like bob"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=be+like+bob&safe=strict&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE35bOqKDaAhUbOsAKHaaXBLYQsAQIKA&biw=1422&bih=659)

Comment: @QHarr - isn't that supposed to be ["be like bill"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be_like_Bill)?

Comment: @QHarr  That *must* be it.  :)

Comment: As I interpreted it, OP is using a trick to get the image from the clipboard: open up a blank excel worksheet, execute a paste (pasting the image that's currently on the clipboard), save the pasted image to a jpg. The current code looks so non-functional, however, that I can't tell. But using that trick this should be possible.

Comment: In case of VBA I'm self taught. I know that my code may look like... well not very proffesional but I'm trying to do my best. I'm out of ideas how to save picture from clipboard to jpg file without using excel (only MS Access VBA).

Comment: @KrzysztofDrabik - I, too, am self taught VBA (I think most of us are).  No need to be perfect; just always willing to improve & take advice. ;)  As for your issue, I've put a lot of thought into it (this post has been a shortcut on my desktop staring at me all week!) and I don't think it's easily possible without using 3rd party tools. That being said, there are always alternative solutions.  For example, I still don't understand why you require [JPG compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) specifically. Other formats could be easier to work with.

Comment: @ashleedawg I picked jpg because it is commonly used but if png or tiff will do the job then why not. I just want to save hdd space. As I mentioned before I managed to use freeimage.dll library to convert bmp to jpg but I still don't know how to create image object from clipboard that this library accepts. I'll try to ask in [project's site](https://sourceforge.net/p/freeimage/discussion/36109/).

Comment: @KrzysztofDrabik as I stated, any image on the clipboard is stored as a Bitmap... so you're saying if you could save the image from the clipboard at a `.BMP` file then you can handle the conversion?

Comment: @ashleedawg yes, I can handle conversion from .bmp to .jpg with freeimage.dll. I managed to convert tiff to jpg, I checked their documentation and bmp is also listed as input. Freeimage has function to save screenshot of whole screen or specific app window (by its ID) but it doesn't solve my problem - I want to save only selected part of screen. In problem description I mentioned working code but it works in excel, not in access.